# How to develop an simple application for Blackberry that allows me to send and receive data from mysql server

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

I want to develop an simple application for a blackberry that allows me to send and receive data from a MySQL server. I am not that familiar with Java Mobile Programming but am aware I need some sort of web service/servlet. I have been trying to find out how I can do this from blackberry tutorials/forums but without success. Basically I want to query a MySQL database from a blackberry and want the result returned. Can anyone tell me how I can do this or provide sample code? Or offer any easier alternatives?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. If you read the faq you'll learn that your question is not answerable by us in its current state. You have to start coding first and show us some code... I suggest you [start here](http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_choice/index.html)

Comment: You will want to have some sort of API service that returns JSON code preferabbly.  However you need to specify in your question a few things, for example on the server side what language do you plan on using? e.g. java/php/dotnet/etc.   For the mobile side, what version(s) of blackberry are you targeting and what languages? (e.g. you mention java mobile but the tags you have added are blackberry-webworks and blackberry-10 - neither of which use java).

Comment: Alright, first of all: If you are talking about Java development on BlackBerrys you will target BlacBerry 7 not BlackBerry 10.
But if you want to target BB10 you cannot use Java, there are 5 different methods to target it.

And like the post above, please give some more information.